# UISplitViewController detail view hide UITabBarController in compact mode

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with a root UITabBarController that contains a few UISplitViewControllers. Everything works as expected, except when the split view is collapsed I would like to be able to hide the tab bar. I'm pushing the new detail view controller with `[self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:detailNav sender:self];` and all attempts to call `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` have failed. Everything is laid out in code, I don't use storyboards.

Is this even possible, or am I stuck with the tab bar if I use a split view controller on an iPhone?

Comment: I am really struggling with this same issue. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: @SAHM Sort of, I ended up manually moving the tab bar out of the way by shifting it off screen

Comment: same problem for me! i've swift 5

Comment: Would also be super interested in a solution to the problem...